# Higher Moment in Gaussian

Tags: probability

Prove that for $X$ a Gaussian random variable, all moments after the third are zero, that is
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^n] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n P_X(x)dx = 0,\qquad n\geq 3
$$

Comment: In one word: Antisymmetry.

Comment: This is only true for odd $n$'s. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2FSqrt%5B2+Pi%5Dx%5E4+e%5E%7B-x%5E2%2F2%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C-infty%2C+infty%7D

Comment: Maybe James meant cumulants: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Cumulants_of_some_continuous_probability_distributions

Answer (score 2):

They are not zero. If it is zero mean then the odds moments will be zero, but the even ones are not.

Answer (score 1):

In its current formulation, this statement is $\textbf{false}$.

If we look at the case $n = 4$, we basically have to integrate the function $x \mapsto x^{4} e^{- \frac{x^{2}}{2}}$, which a stricly positive function on the entire $\mathbb{R}$-axis.

However, if we suppose that the gaussian is $\textbf{centered}$ (meaning its mean is $0$), we can look at the case n odd, $n > 3$. We have to integrate a function of the form $f : x \mapsto x^{2n + 1} e^{- \frac{x^{2}}{2}}$. As this function is an odd function ($f (- x) = f (x)$), the integral $\int f (x) \, dx$ shrinks down to $0$. So that, in conclusion, for every odd $n \geq 3$, the moments of a centered Gaussian distribution are $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is normally distributed, $n$ is odd and $E[X]=0$ then $X^n$ and $-X^n$ have the same distribution, so $E[X^n]=-E[X^n]$ wich leads to $E[X^n]=0$.

In general the statement in your question is not true.